# Making game with automatic enemy number/speed increases at certain score increments - how to achieve logically?

Tags: java, loops, logic, processing, game-engine

Update: Added in some more details so a bit more context is given to the snippet of code I gave.

I recently submitted a game I made in Processing as part of my university coursework, but it didn't turn out exactly how I wanted it to, so I'm working on adding some features and re-coding some of it to make it more fun and replayable.

Anyway, the problem I'm having is with enemy wave generation. How my game works is that there is a class specifically for a single enemy instance, and I made an ArrayList for enemy generation. The below code has a for loop that sets itself depending on the amount of waves set as the integer waveCount. It adds a number of enemies to the ArrayList equal to the value waveCount, and then shows the enemies on the screen. The enemy is removed individually if they are shot, and if they touch the player, the player's health is reduced, then the player position is reset, as are the enemy's positions. They simply come from the top of the screen and move down towards the player at the bottom, slowly orientating themselves to the player's x and y position.

I have the enemy waves working correctly, but in the last version of my game I manually increased the waves as the player reaches certain scores with if statements, and now I want to figure out a way to have the game automatically add a wave when the player score reaches a 200 increment. I also want the enemy speed to increase slightly every time the play score reaches a 1000 increment.

Right now, the way I've coded it leads to it it only increasing the number of waves *once* at 200/400/600/etc before going back to a single wave. I've handled the enemies as an ArrayList of classes. If anyone can help me figure out a way to code an automated, infinite wave system, with one wave being added at score increments of 200, and the enemy speed increasing at score increments of 1000, that would be MASSIVELY helpful!

```
updateWave = false;
hasAddedWave = false;
scoreCheck = score.score;
enemySpeedX = 0.6;
enemySpeedY = 1;

waveCount = 1;

if(scoreCheck > 0 && scoreCheck % 200 == 0 && hasAddedWave == false){
  updateWave = true;
}

if(updateWave == true && hasAddedWave == false){
  waveCount += 1;
  hasAddedWave = true;
}

if(updateWave == true && hasAddedWave == true){
  updateWave = false;
  hasAddedWave = false;
}

for(int i = 0; i < waveCount; i++){
  zombiePosition = random(100,400);
  zombies.add(new Enemy(zombiePosition,-50,enemySpeedX,enemySpeedY));
  zombies.get(i).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a question that exists outside of your game? You've obviously omitted lots of code here, so your question really needs to make sense in relation to the code you're showing (which isn't Processing code on its own, this wouldn't compile)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, what you need is a way to say :

`"Hey, this guy reached 200 points further than before! Let's throw a new wave at him! "`

Just by that sentence you can easily deduce that it's going to pass a LOT by repetitive cicles, evidently I cannot give you a code sample, as I can't guess what your code is (as someone already pointed, you haven't given us much to work with) . Try out something such as

`if (pointsNow >= pointsBefore+200) doSomething`

Furthermore, the reason why it goes back to a single wave is :

```
if(scoreCheck > 0 && scoreCheck % 200 == 0 && hasAddedWave == false){
   updateWave = true;
      }
```

What this if-statement means that `scoreCheck`is bigger than 0, AND divisible by 200. Which means that scoreCheck divided by 200 has a remainder of 0. Imagine if your player gets a score of 401, the score check wouldn't be able to be divided by 200, as the remained is NOT 0. Instead, try to:

`scoreCheck > lastScoreCheck` where you add 200 to lastScoreCheck (or whatever ammount you want)

And finally, about the speed, once again, play with the variables. Instead of having `speed = 1` (for example)  have : `speed = 1 + level*multiplier` , what this do is it sets the speed to a certain value in this case, 1, and adds a multiplier, which is depended by another variable which would be the level. You can manipulate it to make the game easier or harder, for example : `speed = 1 + level*5` is a LOT faster than `speed = 1 + level*0.5`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that by level, I mean anything you want, I used level, in your case you can deduce an expression based on your "levels" made by intervals of 200 points. One example would be speed =  baseSpeed + currentPoints/400  which would result in a small increase of speed (less than 30% )

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm having a similar issue. If scoreCheck is bigger than 0, and ScoreCheck % 200 == 0, then 200 is added to lastScoreCheck. If scoreCheck >= lastScoreCheck, then the wave amount is increased. Once the score is no longer divisible by 200, the if statement is no longer valid and thus the waveCount reverts back to being 1. Any other ideas?

Comment: The point is, you don't use %200, because it will, eventually not be divisible by 200. Instead, use a counter with a if-statement, if bigger than your previous score plus a certain number, then create a new wave

Comment: AHHH OKAY! Thanks for replying so quickly! I've got a working piece of wave code now, but the issue is that it only adds a single wave, and keeps it at two waves max. How should I proceed?

    waveAdjust = 0;
    waveCount = 1;
    scoreCheck = score.score;
    lastScoreCheck = 0;
    
    if(scoreCheck >= lastScoreCheck + 200){
      lastScoreCheck += 200;
      waveAdjust++;
      waveCount += waveAdjust;
    }

Comment: Now put a cicle on it, so it will repeat that piece of code whenever you reach the ammount of points needed, I'm tired, but IMO, an if-statement regarding scoreCheck > lastScore , and a loop with those elements within should do the trick, anyway, I'm off for tonight, I'll stop by tomorrow if you need more help =)

Comment: Hey man, I *finally* managed to get the waves working! I made it so that when scoreCheck => lastScoreCheck + 200, it runs a method addWave(), then adds 200 to lastScoreCheck. AddWave() simply adds a single enemy to the ArrayList, makes it visible, then the method ends. Problem solved! Anyway, I've now got a different problem to do with PVectors, but since you seemed to help before and seem to know your stuff, do you have an email or some way I can personally talk with you about it since there's no messaging option on stackOverflow?

Comment: I have an e-mail, although I rarely remember to check it, could work on Skype though, as I'm mostly there

Comment: By the way, just as an idea, if you plan on adding different dificulties, instead of 200 add a variable which changes with the difficulty (eg: easy = 300 , medium = 200, hardasshit = 1)

Comment: Hokay, what's your Skype? As for difficulty settings I want it to be as accessible and easy to get into as possible, so instead I've made it so every time the score reaches 1,000 or so, the enemy speed gets significantly faster.